# обособление "на сегодняшний день"

Tags: пунктуация

Исходя из неточной информации, указаной на сайте, нашей компании(,) на сегодняшний день(,) либо 8, либо 9 лет.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из неточной информации, указанной на сайте, нашей компании на сегодняшний день  либо 8, либо 9 лет.

Обстоятельство "на сегодняшний день" **входит в основное сообщение и не обособляется.** Если на сайте указана дата создания компании, то ее возраст  определяется на текущий момент, соответствующий дате написания данного сообщения. **Других вариантов нет**, поэтому "на сегодняшний день" **не является уточнением** и не обособляется.

Answer (score 0):

> ...нашей компании(,) на сегодняшний день(,) либо 8, либо 9 лет.

Запятые на месте скобок не нужны.

> Желательно с правилами

Правилами, по-моему, обычно обосновывается нужность в определённых местах того или иного знака препинания. А вот обосновать ненужность...

**P.S.**

*...указаННой.*

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ошибка печати.